# What is the price for an enchanted weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

The DMG describes enchanted weapons, but does not say the prices for most. I'm wondering if there is is a scale or chart, or can you only buy some of them? If possible, can you provide an example?

Comment: 3 levels of experience and 3 Lapis. Depending on the level of the enchantments

Comment: What is Lapis? And do you mean lose three levels?

Answer (score 3):

There are two components to this answer, both of which are found in the DMG on page 135, near the heading 'Buying and Selling.'

1. In 5E, magic items are exceedingly rare. According to the DMG,
   unless the DM decides otherwise, anything rarer than a simple Potion
   of Healing simply isn't for sale. They are too precious. In general,
   you find magic items, you don't buy them. If any are available for
   sale at all, that is strictly at the DM's Prerogative. But the
   general assumption is 'no.'
2. However, if you want to allow buying magic items in your campaign,
   estimated values based on rarity are also found on page 135, in the
   Magic Item Rarity table.

If you would like rules to use as a reference for this, the [Unearthed Arcana for Downtime Activities](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UA_Downtime.pdf) does include rules for trying to find someone selling a magic item, and how to determine what they have for sale. However, Unearthed Arcana is strictly Playtest Rules and may not be admissible in whatever game you are playing.

Answer (score 3):

Magic items are not purchasable without your DM's permission. If your DM allows it, the DMG (p.135) recommends about 500 gp for a uncommon item (example: +1 weapon) and 5,000 gp for a rare item (example: +2 weapon).

If you are in Adventurers' League, you will likely be able to soon buy a +1 weapon from your faction for 500 gp (check with your AL DM for further information).

Answer (score 1):

Typically you cannot buy magic items in 5e (with the exception of healing potions)  and magic weapons are exceedingly rare.  As such, there are no set prices and the DMG goes so far as to say that even *selling* magic items might be difficult.

For prices on magic weapons, you will need to set them yourself if you are the DM, or ask your DM if there are any available for purchase.

Comment: Not true.  There not being a magical item market just means you can't walk up to a store and expect to be able to pick any item from the DMG, and have it delivered to your castle in a week.  There are still magical items for sale, they are just more rare.  You will have to ask what they have, rather than assume they can get what you want.

Comment: @Shem "There are still magical items for sale, they are just more rare." is *only* true if your DM makes it so.

Answer (score 0):

The DMG on pg 135 lists the cost range of magical items by rarity.  If you are the DM, feel free to pick a price within that range if you think that item should be more expensive, or just roll to determine a price.  There are also homebrew rules out there that can help if you want to start introducing market forces like having a small village charge more than a large city for the same item.

The DMG also says that there is no magical item economy.  This does not mean that you cannot purchase magical items in the standard 5e setting, or that there are not magical item shops that sell things.  It just means there is not a catalog that you can go to, request a specific item, and then have it show up in shop a week later.  It means that the shops come pre-populated with whatever items they have, and if a PC wants a specific one, they should chase down rumors of where they can find one and get it that way.

Comment: "It means that the shops come pre-populated with whatever items they have, and if a PC wants a specific one, they should chase down rumors of where they can find one and get it that way."  This is a big leap of logic to go from "there is no magic item economy" to "you can buy magic items, just not specific ones you're looking for."  There is no guidance for pre-populating shops with magic items, and in fact magic items are considered an optional rule in 5e.