# Can you buy a magic item in between campaigns?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I know that players can buy magic items, ([What is the price for an enchanted weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98948/what-is-the-price-for-an-enchanted-weapon)), but do you have to buy them in a city, or can you do it in downtime.

Comment: I have voted to close this as opinion based since each DM will have his / her own views on this.  Is your question "as a player" or "as a DM" ... it matters.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I don't disagree, but that comment seems like most of a good answer.

Comment: @fectin I even think this is a dupe, and it matters if the question is being asked from the DM or Player PoV before an answer could be offered. In Fact, an [answer has already been given to this poster here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/98951/22566).  In a simple search using tags [dnd-5e] and [magic-items] I note the same basic question coming up from this poster.

Comment: In what way does the first answer to the linked question you asked not answer this question?  Closing as unclear to get clarification on what we're missing.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, but it's up to the DM.

Some weak magic items can be bought, but anything rare/more powerful is up to the DM. The DMG suggests that it buying magic items should be difficult and adventure-worthy: (DMG 135)

> Unless you decide your campaign works otherwise, most magic items are so rare that they aren't available for purchase. Common items, such as a potion of healing, can be procured from an alchemist, herbalist, or spellcaster. Doing so is rarely as simple as walking into a shop and selecting an item from a shelf. The seller might ask for a service, rather than coin.
>
> In a large city with an academy of magic or a major temple, buying and selling magic items might be possible, at your discretion. ... it's likely to remain similar to the market for fine art in the real world, with invitation-only auctions and a tendency to attract thieves.